# OrientDB Traverse until class X

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

How can I traverse a graph from a node until a node of type X and no further?
The assumption is that eventually all paths lead to X.

I tried this query but it still give me paths which continue past entities of type X

traverse * from #32:3
WHILE not($current instanceof 'X')

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

`traverse * from #32:3 WHILE $current.@class <> 'X'`

This is not polymorphic, so it works only for instances of type X, not its subclasses.

Note that using `*` wildcard means traversing all edges of any type. Is this what you want? It's always better to specify the direction and/or the edge label(s) to have better performance.

Comment: Thanks Luca, but is there a polymorphic solution?

Comment: You can try `traverse * from #32:3 WHILE ( not( $current instanceof 'X') )` but I'm not sure if this works with 2.2.x

Comment: There is parenthesis after the WHILE.